# Distance between 2 arduino's using rf links

Tags: communication, arduino, wireless

I currently have a setup where I send a char using a Tx of 434MHz and an Uno to a Mega with a Rx. The Mega counts how many times it receives the char and then if it falls below a certain number it triggers an alarm. Is this a viable way to measure the distance between two microcontrollers while indoors or is there a better way.

**Transmitter (Mega)**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int rxPin=2; //Goes to the Receiver Pin
int txPin=5; //Make sure it is set to pin 5 going to input of receiver

SoftwareSerial txSerial = SoftwareSerial(rxPin, txPin);
SoftwareSerial rxSerial = SoftwareSerial(txPin, rxPin);
char sendChar ='H';

void setup() {
  pinMode(rxPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(txPin,OUTPUT);
  txSerial.begin(2400);
  rxSerial.begin(2400);
}

void loop() {
  txSerial.println(sendChar);
  Serial.print(sendChar);
}
```

**Receiver**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//Make sure it is set to pin 5 going to the data input of the transmitter
int rxPin=5; 
int txPin=3; //Don't need to make connections
int LED=13;
int BUZZ=9;
int t=0;

char incomingChar = 0;
int counter = 0;

SoftwareSerial rxSerial = SoftwareSerial(rxPin, txPin);

void setup() {
  pinMode(rxPin, INPUT); //initilize rxpin as input
  pinMode(BUZZ, OUTPUT); //initilize buzz for output
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT); //initilize led for output
  rxSerial.begin(2400); //set baud rate for transmission
  Serial.begin(2400); //see above
}

void loop() {
  for(int i=0; i<200; i++) {
    incomingChar = rxSerial.read(); //read incoming msg from tx

    if (incomingChar =='H') {
      counter++; //if we get bit "h" count it  
    }
    delay(5); //delay of 10 secs
  }
  Serial.println(incomingChar);
  Serial.println(counter); //prints the the bits we recieved

  if(counter<55) {
    //if we receive less than 100 bits than print out of range triggers alarm
    Serial.println("out of range"); 
    tone(BUZZ,5000,500);digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
  }
  else {
    noTone(BUZZ);digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    //if we get more than 100 bits than we are within range turn off alarm
    Serial.println("in range"); 
  }

  counter = 0;
  incomingChar=0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this will give you a measure of distance?  In order to suggest a solution: 1) what level of accuracy do you need; 2) what other limitations do you have (cost, etc); 3) is there a free line-of-sight between these; 4) what range of distances are you interested in?

Comment: 1)must be pretty accurate sorry if that isn't an exact number 2)cost must be low trying to keep it under $50 not including uno and mega 3)line of sight is free 4)interested in short range namely 15ft

Comment: There's nothing built into the arduino that can easily measure distance like this.  You'd probably be better off in a forum other than stackoverflow, since this is basically a hardware question.  Some ideas though are: an acoustic or ultrasonic communication, light intensity or other signal strength, measure the spacing between two lights separated by a known distance, a laser range finder, etc.

Comment: You might get a better response if you ask your question on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thx Matthew I'l try over there

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could achieve distance measuring by making the uno send a message which the mega would echo back. That would give the uno a round-trip time for message propagation between the arduinos. You would have to approximate the processing delays. After that it is basic physics. That is basically the same as how radar works. The actual delay would be something like

t<sub>roundtrip</sub> = t<sub>uno send</sub> + 2*t<sub>propagation</sub> + t<sub>mega receive</sub> + t<sub>mega send</sub> + t<sub>uno receive</sub>

I am guessing the distance you are trying to achieve is in the order of meters. Required resolution is going to be an issue, because `s = vt => t = s/v`, where `s` is the distance between your arduinos and `v = c` in case of radio waves. As the transmission delays should stay constant, you have to be able to measure differences in the order of `1/c` second intervals, basically. I am not very familiar with arduinos, so I do not know if they are capable of this kind of measurements.

Comment: Maybe this would work with acoustics (speed ~300 m/s so delay ~0.03sec), but there's no way it would work with light (speed ~300,000,000 so delay ~0.03 microsec).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use an ultrasonic range finder like the [Maxbotix HRLV-EZ4](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/11309) sold by Sparkfun.
It is within your price range and it should be able to measure distances up to 5m/195 inches with 1mm resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to do it, I have seen it be done with other microcontrollers. Therefore using arduino you would have to solve the equations,fit in arduino language and make a lot of measurements to value discrepancies over communication itself. Do not forget about atmospheric attenuation wich need to be known and fit in the equations. Humidity may deviate electromagnetic waves.